# Append a string in front of line in java?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a pattern lock based project in android.
I have a file called `category.txt`
The content of the file is as below

`Sports:Race:Arcade:`

No what i want is that whenever the user draw a pattern for a specific games category the pattern should get append in front of that category.

eg :
`Sports:Race:"string/pattern string to be appended here for race"Arcade:`
i have used following code but it is not working.

```
private void writefile(String getpattern,String category)
{

    String str1;
    try {
        file = new RandomAccessFile(filewrite, "rw");

        while((str1 = file.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String line[] = str1.split(":");
            if(line[0].toLowerCase().equals(category.toLowerCase()))
            {
                String colon=":";
                file.write(category.getBytes());
                file.write(colon.getBytes());
                file.write(getpattern.getBytes());
                file.close();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"In Writefile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

please help !

Comment: What exactly does not work? I tried it and got to the problem that although the file is closed (s. `file.close()` call) the loop continues. This causes an IOException.

Comment: i don't know why it is not working for me.
can you please provide me with some could which will read the file and append a string for eg."any string" in front of the Race:"String to append".

Comment: To make sure I understood this correctly: your file contains just one line like `Sports:Race:Arcade:`. If the given category matches the element in the string (like `Race`) you want to append the provided pattern in front of the category and write it back to the same file?

Comment: no my files contains multiple lines i.e Sports: in 1st line then Race: on 2nd line then Arcade: on 3rd line and so on.
So now i want to append the pattern in front of Race: and rest of the content should be as it is

Answer (score 0):

Using `RandomAccessFile` you have to calculate the position. I think it's much easier to just replace the file content with a little help from apache-commons-io `FileUtils`. This might be not the best idea if you have a very large file but it's quite simple.

```
    String givenCategory = "Sports";
    String pattern = "stringToAppend";
    final String colon = ":";
    try {
        List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("someFile.txt"));
        String modifiedLine = null;
        int index = 0;
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] categoryFromLine = line.split(colon);
            if (givenCategory.equalsIgnoreCase(categoryFromLine[0])) {
                modifiedLine = new StringBuilder().append(pattern).append(colon).append(givenCategory).append(colon).toString();
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        if (modifiedLine != null) {
            lines.set(index, modifiedLine);
            FileUtils.writeLines(new File("someFile.txt"), lines);
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // do something
    }
```